# Can't start the MapReduce job

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

When I tried to start simple wordcount mapreduce example, I got this

```
[cloudera-scm@ivana-namenode2 /opt/MapReduce/wordcount]$ pydoop script    wc.py /user/cloudera-scm/Mapduce/wordcount/data/text /user/cloudera-scm/MapReduce/wordcount/output
18/08/14 14:11:49 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.cache.files is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files
18/08/14 14:11:49 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
18/08/14 14:11:49 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
18/08/14 14:11:49 INFO Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.pipes.java.recordreader is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.pipes.isjavarecordreader
18/08/14 14:11:49 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.cache.archives is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.archives
18/08/14 14:11:49 INFO Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.pipes.java.recordwriter is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.pipes.isjavarecordwriter
18/08/14 14:11:49 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.textoutputformat.separator is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator
18/08/14 14:11:49 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.compress.map.output is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress
18/08/14 14:11:50 INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to rm59
18/08/14 14:11:51 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
18/08/14 14:11:51 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
18/08/14 14:11:52 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
18/08/14 14:11:52 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1534248543348_0007
18/08/14 14:11:52 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
18/08/14 14:11:52 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1534248543348_0007
18/08/14 14:11:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ivana-namenode2:8088/proxy/application_1534248543348_0007/
18/08/14 14:11:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1534248543348_0007
18/08/14 14:15:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1534248543348_0007 running in uber mode : false
18/08/14 14:15:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/08/14 14:15:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1534248543348_0007 failed with state KILLED due to: Application killed by user.
18/08/14 14:15:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
18/08/14 14:15:07 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pydoop", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop/app/main.py", line 81, in main
args.func(args, unknown)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop/app/script.py", line 130, in run
scripter.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop/app/script.py", line 119, in run
submitter.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop/app/submit.py", line 376, in run
logger=self.logger, keep_streams=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop/hadut.py", line 302, in run_class
keep_streams=keep_streams)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydoop/hadut.py", line 167, in run_cmd
raise RunCmdError(p.returncode, ' '.join(_args), error)
pydoop.hadut.RunCmdError: command exited with 1 status
```

Also, when i tried to start jar example i got this same problem, so it's not about code.

Below, you have link to my main.py, script.py and submit.py. I can't put them here because stack overflow limits up to 30000 characters

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1mabmgfywa38xib/AAB946SUK8-A8VfWfieQG_4ha?dl=0

Comment: Could you provide us with your `script.py`, `main.py` and `submit.py` files ? As it is know, we can't say where your issue is coming from, and what caused it.

Comment: Hi, i've edited post, you can now see my main.py, script.py and submit.py on dropbox link. @Mornor

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code itself, not as a link

Comment: Anyway, `The url to track the job` tells you why it failed, but your logs also say your code was "killed by the user"

Comment: Like i said, stack overflow limits up to 30000 characters, so i can't put code. Logs say that but i am user and i am sure that i didn't kill it. @cricket_007

Comment: Can you go to the url in the logs there and find out the actual error?

Comment: From that same machine, run `yarn logs -applicationId application_1534248543348_0007`

Comment: I visited url and there is nothing about error, at beginning it says that state is accepted and final status undefined and when wc.py breaks state is killed and final status is killed. @cricket_007

Comment: You need to show the contents of `wc.py`. The files you posted to Dropbox are Pydoop modules. Also, this is more an "I'm having trouble using Pydoop" thing than a programming question.